# Details: Could not load file or assembly 'BarcodeLib, Version=1.0.0.19 or one of its dependencies

Tags: reporting-services, barcode, ssrs-2008-r2

Earlier I'm using the VS2013 with 3.5 framework but now I installed VisualStudio 2017 when I open the report project it converts the project to latest framework and then when I try to build the project it throws the following error :

I'm using 3rd party library barcodeLib for barcode and font adjustments where every I use the lib I have already referenced in the respective report files.

Any one have idea on this issue

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
    Error       [rsErrorLoadingCodeModule] Error while loading code module: ‘BarcodeLib, Version=1.0.0.19, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null’. Details: Could not load file or assembly 'BarcodeLib, Version=1.0.0.19, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.      C:\softwares\End.rdl    0   
    Error       [rsCompilerErrorInClassInstanceDeclaration] Error in class instance declaration for class BarcodeLib.Barcode: [BC30002] Type 'BarcodeLib.Barcode' is not defined.       C:\softwares\End.rdl    0   
    Error       [rsCompilerErrorInCode] There is an error on line 328 of custom code: [BC30451] 'BarcodeLib' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.       C:\softwares\End.rdl    0   
    Error       [rsCompilerErrorInCode] There is an error on line 33 of custom code: [BC30451] 'BarcodeLib' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.        C:\softwares\Projects\App.rdl   0   
    Error       [rsCompilerErrorInClassInstanceDeclaration] Error in class instance declaration for class Barcodelib.Barcode: [BC30002] Type 'Barcodelib.Barcode' is not defined.       C:\softwares\App.rdl    0   
    Error       [rsErrorLoadingCodeModule] Error while loading code module: ‘BarcodeLib, Version=1.0.0.19, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null’. Details: Could not load file or assembly 'BarcodeLib, Version=1.0.0.19, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.      C:\softwares\App.rdl    0   
    Error       [rsErrorLoadingCodeModule] Error while loading code module: ‘BarcodeLib, Version=1.0.0.19, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null’. Details: Could not load file or assembly 'BarcodeLib, Version=1.0.0.19, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.      C:\softwares\AppChild.rdl   0   
    Error       [rsCompilerErrorInCode] There is an error on line 44 of custom code: [BC30451] 'BarcodeLib' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.        C:\softwares\AppChild.rdl   0   
    Error       [rsCompilerErrorInClassInstanceDeclaration] Error in class instance declaration for class Barcodelib.Barcode: [BC30002] Type 'Barcodelib.Barcode' is not defined.       C:\softwares\AppChild.rdl   0   
    Error       [rsCompilerErrorInCode] There is an error on line 13 of custom code: [BC30451] 'BarcodeLib' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.        C:\softwares\Cancellation.rdl   0   
    Error       [rsCompilerErrorInClassInstanceDeclaration] Error in class instance declaration for class Barcodelib.Barcode: [BC30002] Type 'Barcodelib.Barcode' is not defined.       C:\softwares\Cancellation.rdl   0
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't compile/load in VS2019, Barcodelib version 1.1.0.0 that was being used in a Report Definition File so I ended up registering the dll into the GAC which seemed to work.